# How do I get the heat sink bracket off on the Mac Pro 2013 (trash can)?

Tags: mac-pro, cpu

I have a Mac Pro 2013 which I bought in 2018.  I’ve read they are upgradeable (macsales.com has a video on how to do it).  I bought a 12 core chip to replace the 6 core chip it came with.

I tore the whole thing down and got to the heat sink retainer clip.  Every video or website I’ve read (iFixIt has a text version, and there are several videos on YouTube including the OWC video) shows a total of 8 screws.  Four outer screws, which I think are T8.  And four inner screws.  The four inner screws are not screws on my unit.  They’re just round nubs.  I’ve applied a little bit of pressure attempting to pry them loose but they won’t budge.  I don’t want to get too rough with it because I don’t want to damage the board or the original CPU given it seems like Apple changed this to be not-upgradeable.

What I’m a missing here?  Was such a change made?  Is it safe to pry until they pop off, or are they rivets and not designed to be removable?

[image: Photo of heat sink retainer clip showing the four inner fittings]

Comment: Could you annotate the picture and circle the screws you want to remove? I cannot see them

Comment: It's a bit confusing to say "The four inner screws are not screws on my unit" and might be better to say "The four inner fittings are not screws on my unit". Presumably, you are referring to the four black circles, that are [highlighted in the image in the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2GI8.jpg)..?

Answer (score 1):

There are no T10 Torx screws holding the CPU heat sink bracket.[image]

Comment: Are they plastic covers?

Comment: I must be missing something... why have you mentioned T10 screws, and saying that there aren't any? The OP mentioned T8 for the outer screws. What are the four fittings that you have circled... it would be more useful to [edit] your answer to say what they *are* instead of what they *aren't*.